# Cannot enter decimal point in primeNG p-columnFilter

Tags: primeng

I am using p-table and p-columnFilter components in a modal in my angular project.

I am using the following libraries:

```
"primeflex": "^2.0.0",
"primeicons": "^4.1.0",
"primeng": "^11.2.0",
"@angular/cli": "^11.2.5",
```

here my HTML:

```
<th>
    <div class="flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
            Pressure ({{pressureUnits}})
        <p-columnFilter type="numeric" field="tyre_pressure" display="menu">
        </p-columnFilter>
    </div>
</th>
```

Except for the input generated inside the p-column, everything is good.
Only numbers can be entered into the filter, not decimals.

Typing 56.8 into the input or paste 56.8 into the input does not work.

[image]

** SOLUTION **
using yoelb00 answer this is the code that worked:

```
<div class="flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
    Pressure ({{pressureUnits}})
    <p-columnFilter field="tyre_pressure" matchMode="equals" display="menu">
        <ng-template pTemplate="filter" let-value let-filter="filterCallback">
            <input type="number" pInputText [ngModel]="value" (ngModelChange)="filter($event)" class="p-inputtext">
        </ng-template>
    </p-columnFilter>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ng-template and you can write your own input,
it will solve your problem

```
  <p-columnFilter type="number" field="tyre_pressure" display="menu">
    <ng-template pTemplate="filter" let-value let-filter="filterCallback">
                    <input type="number" pInputText [ngModel]="value" (ngModelChange)="filter($event)" class="p-inputtext"> </ng-template>
  </p-columnFilter>
```

Comment: Beautiful, any idea how to add more filter options like greater than, less that, etc?

Comment: You just need to press on the equals word in the filter menu , then you can choose greater than , less than etc..

Comment: Sorry @yoelb00. The code provided only creates the input =box with a single drop down on top having only 2 options: 'match all' and 'match any'

Answer (score 3):

There are two input parameters for p-columnFilter component you could use. These are minFractionDigits and maxFractionDigits. If you provide them you should be able to type decimal values. Please see example below:

```
    <p-columnFilter
      type="numeric"
      [minFractionDigits]="2"
      [maxFractionDigits]="2"
      field="outcomePriceYes"
      display="menu"
      class="p-ml-auto"
    ></p-columnFilter>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use pipes like the currency in the following example

```
Price <p-columnFilter type="numeric" field="finalPrice" display="menu" currency="SAR"></p-columnFilter> <p-sortIcon field="finalPrice"></p-sortIcon>
```

Comment: This seems to work only if you add the currency, but in my case the field decimal number I don't want the currency symbol. Any idea how to achieve that?

Comment: you can use the answer of @yoelb00

Answer (score -1):

you can use minfractiondigits.

```
 <p-columnFilter type="numeric" field="qtyMinLvl" display="menu" [minFractionDigits]="2"></p-columnFilter>
```